# How do I disable or lock lookup fields on a Visual Force page?

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have a visual force page where I want to disable the user from editing some of the fields on it. I used the css class attribute to identify these fields.

Input Textboxes were disabled successfully using this approach, but the lookup fields are still accessible.

How can I disable the lookup fields so that the user is unable to make any changes?

**Declaration of Field:**

`<apex:inputField styleClass="makeSelectReadOnly" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" required="true"/>`

**JQuery to disable the field:**

`jQuery(".makeSelectReadOnly").attr("disabled","true");`

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of VF page]

Comment: use the same jquery to hide the lookup icon element......

Comment: This looks promising. I just need to find out where the element is.

Comment: ```jQuery(".lookupIcon").hide();``` works, but also hides the icon for the Opportunity Owner which needs to stay. :)

Comment: If you are ok with just showing the account name (without the disabled input), just use apex:outputField

Comment: if you really want to use jquery, try `jQuery('.makeSelectReadOnly').next().click(function(e){e.preventDefault();})`

Comment: You will have to use your selector for the input field then use .find() or .closest() to find the .lookupicon. but this is  becoming off topic. I would just use output text and output the account name in lieu of the input when needed. So something like `jQuery('.makeSelectReadOnly').attr('disabled','true').closest('.lookupIcon').hide();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JQeury doesn't handle the lookup button..

In case it is always disable consider using instead : apx:outputField

If it depend on criteria you can add both input & output but show only 1 of them:

```
<apex:inputField styleClass="makeSelectReadOnly" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" required="true" rendered="{!openForEdit==true}"/>
<apex:outputield styleClass="makeSelectReadOnly" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" rendered="{!openForEdit==false}"/>
```

Comment: This is what I have done with all the dateFields on the page and I was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: @SantanuBoral `<apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}"/>` works just fine for me in a visualforce page being displayed on one of my standard layouts.

Comment: Gotta agree with going with standard functionality in this case. This is exactly what the `<apex:output*>` components were meant to do. +1 from me.

Comment: Again, you can use only <apex:outputField...  if it's always should be disabled.

Comment: I had to do this in order to make this work the way I wanted. I am now hiding / showing the field or text depending on the view mode.

Answer (score 4):

My thoughts on this would be to use the `<apex:outputField />` tag on occasions that you don't want the user to be able to edit the field.

```
<apex:inputField rendered="{!NOT(makeSelectReadOnly)}" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" required="true"/>
<apex:outputField rendered="{!makeSelectReadOnly}" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" required="true"/>
```

Where `makeSelectReadOnly` is a boolean variable populated in the apex class.

Just know that if you mark it as `required="true"` and the field has no value,  it will cause the page to error.